# Parsing a txt file vertically

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a text file like below

```
Shipto: abc def        Soldto: XYZ EFG        From: JANGO
        Shipto addr            Soldto addr          FromAddr
        PO - 1000              PO-2000              PO-3000
```

I need to parse this file and store the ship to, sold to and from addresses to DB using Java. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a scanner to read the txt file and store it in a String. You could then parse the String and store it in a DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I read the text I get the whole line to the string right ? I need to store these values separately like the shipto alone soldto alone like that

Comment: When you split each line then you have separate values. What holds you to process these values individually?